# Gradient decent is not converging even on large value of alpha

Tags: python, machine-learning, gradient-descent

I am trying to implement gradient decent but it's not converging. I can't figure out the problem.
When I implemented gradient decent using `for` loops it converged.
When I switched to using a vectorized approach it stopped converging, even on a large value of alpha. Here are the functions I am using to perform gradient descent.

```
def GenerateData():
    ds = pd.read_csv('./housing.csv', )
    ds = ds.dropna()
    ds = ds.iloc[:400, :]
    X = ds['median_income'].copy()
    y = ds['median_house_value'].copy()
    X = X.to_numpy()
    y = y.to_numpy()
    return X, y

#Non-Vectorized Approach
def average(X, y, W, b):
    N = X.shape[0]
    t_err = 0.0
    for i in range(N):
        t_err += (y[i] - (W * X[i] + b)) ** 2
    
    return t_err/ float(N)
def Grad_descent(X, y, W, b, alpha=0.01):

    N = X.shape[0]
    df_dw = 0
    df_db = 0
    for i in range(N):
        df_dw += -2 * X[i] * (y[i] - ( W * X[i] + b))
        df_db += -2*(y[i] - (W * X[i] + b))
    
    W = W - (1/float(N)) * df_dw * alpha
    b = b - (1/float(N)) * df_db * alpha

    return W, b
```

```
# Vectorized approach
def average(X, y, W, b):
    M = X.shape[0]
    t_err = 0.0
    t_err = np.sum(np.power(y - (X @ W + b), 2))
    return t_err/ (2 * float(M))

def Grad_descent(X, y, alpha=0.01, epcs=10):
    N = X.shape[1]
    M = X.shape[0]

    W = np.zeros(N)
    b = np.ones(M)
    
    df_dW = 0
    df_db = 0
    for e in range(epcs):
        df_dW = np.transpose(X) @ ((X @ W + b) - y)
        df_db = (X @ W + b) - y

        W = W - (1/(2 *float(M))) * df_dW * alpha
        b = b - (1/(2 *float(M))) * df_db * alpha

        print('Epoch:', e, 'loss: ', average(X, y, W, b))

    return W, b
```

I cant figure out why why gradient decent is diverging when using a vectorized approach.

x shape is `(400, 8)` and y shape is `(400, 1)`
Data was taken from housing price prediction dataset
[housing Ds](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/tree/master/datasets/housing)

Comment: Large learning rates can make it hard to converge—especially true for large values, actually. But without your data and the non-vectorized code, we can’t easily compare to help you diagnose it. Could you please provide a [mcve], which is expected when posting on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Thanks for the comment I tried to give the info related to Data and both vectorized and non vectorized approaches.

Comment: Can you share how you call the non-vectorized version i.e. what are the shapes of arguments `W` and `b`? Also, in the vectorized version, you seem to have a bias for each sample! (`b = np.ones(M)` is problematic). You have 1 output so you should have 1 bias term i.e. a scalar.

Comment: W shape is (9,1), b is (400, 1)

Answer (score 0):

Well I was Messing around with alpha[learning rate] a bit and found that 0.001 is too high
I changed it to 1e-10 and it started converging!
and I also refactored and changed the code.

```
def average(X, y, W):
    M = X.shape[0]
    t_err = 0.0
    t_err = np.sum(np.power((X @ W) - y, 2))
    return t_err/ (2 * float(M))

def Grad_descent(X, y, alpha=0.1, epcs=10):
    N = X.shape[1]
    M = X.shape[0]

    W = np.random.randn(N, 1)

    for e in range(epcs):

        df_dW = (2/M) * X.T @ (X @ W - y)
        W = W - alpha * df_dW

        print('Epoch:', e, ' loss:', average(X, y, W))
```

before I was calculating bias term separately but now I merged the bias column with X matrix so Weight Vector first element is for bias term.
learning rate was the issue I guess for gradient decent not converging and also the cost function result was really big which resulted in higher jumps away from the global minimum.